# Does UK Standard Visitor Visa require proof of all the addresses you lived in for past 2 years

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

While filling the UK Standard Visa form, I was asked to enter all the addresses I have lived in past 2 years.

I am living at my current address since 16 months, I have the tenancy agreement to show for it. Before that I used to live in my college dorm room.

Do I need to provide a proof that I used to stay in my college dorm as it comes within the 2 years period of Visa application?

Comment: Does it ask for proof of those addresses?

Comment: Where exactly in the application does it ask for provision of proof of previous addresses?

Comment: I haven't yet submitted the application, I couldn't find any info regarding proofs of addresses other than the current one. I asked here so that if it is required, I would get it done before submitting the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement to prove your address. What is mandatory is confirmation of legal residence, if you are not a national of the country in which you are applying or your right to reside there is not included in your passport. The Guide to Supporting Documrnts https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk makes no mention of proof of address being needed.

Comment: My current address is different than the one I have in my passport, in fact the address in my passport is the same as my college dorm one.
it is hassle here to update your passport address, moreover a new passport is issued if you change your address

Answer (score 0):

Supply proof of your present residence and proof of your collage attendance for that period with the statement that you lived the in a college dorm during that time

- if they require more, they will ask for it

Important is only that truthful answers be given and documented with present documents available.

Comment: I want to prepare all my documents before submitting the application so I need to be  sure that if proof of college dorm is required